# Procedure parameter of type Extractors.Text Encoding for Extractors.Text

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

I'm attempting to generalize a ADLA U-SQL procedure by including parameters for the delimiter, skiprows and encoding on Extractors.Text:

```
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter: @columndelimiter, skipFirstNRows: @skiprows, encoding: @encoding)
```

The encoding value is of type System.Text.Encoding which does not compile when used as the parameter datatype declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Foo
(
@skiprows           int,
@columndelimiter    char,
@rowdelimiter       string,
@encoding           System.Text.Encoding
)
```

Here is how I am declaring and assigning the variables in another U-SQL script to pass into the procedure call:

```
DECLARE @columndelimiter char = '|';
DECLARE @rowdelimiter string = "\n";
DECLARE @encoding System.Text.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

This is fine.  I've also tried declaring and passing encoding as a string but no luck, I get a cast exception.

**Q:** how do I pass the System.Text.Encoding type into the procedure?  or what is the workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm taking a look at this now. Looks like this error pops up even when declaring the variables in the same U-SQL script.  Hopefully I can get back to you soon!

[Update] This bug has been already been identified and fixed internally, and should be rolled out publicly with the next release.